# How I can get the Sum from following Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE AS BIGINT   
SET @VARIABLE = Sum((Select Top 5 SUM(Quantity) FROM Orders Group by MenuItemName Order by Quantity Desc))   
Print @VARIABLE
```

This Will Return a Error :

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery

How I can Achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you want to order the records in `sum(Quantity)` not just `Quantity`

Try this way

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE AS BIGINT

SET @VARIABLE = (SELECT Sum(Quantity)
                 FROM   (SELECT TOP 5 sum(Quantity) Quantity 
                         FROM   Orders
                         GROUP  BY MenuItemName
                         ORDER  BY Quantity DESC) a)

PRINT @VARIABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select @variable =`, and you should probably be ordering by `sum(Quantity) desc`.

```
declare @variable as bigint;

select @variable = Sum(SumQuantity) 
  from (
    select top 5 
        SumQuantity=Sum(Quantity)
      from Orders
      group by MenuItemName
      order by Sum(Quantity) desc
   ) as x;

print @variable;
```